# Using the same if else statement with two variables

Tags: javascript

I have the following if statement:

```
let panoX = 0
if (pano.x === 0) {
  panoX = 0
} else if (pano.x === null) {
  panoX = 200
} else {
  panoX = pano.x
}

// This will be sent in a form
{
  x: panoX,
  y: panoY
}
```

It sets `panoX` based on the value of `pano.x`. But I also have a `pano.y`, that goes through the same if statement. How can I deal with `pano.y` without having to write a new if statement?

(Note: I can't do `x: pano.x || 200` because `0` is falsy in JavaScript. So setting `pano.x` to `0` makes `x:` be `200`.

Comment: Seems like you didn't provide some code, where is pano?

Comment: So what are conditions for panoY? is it same? pano.y===0 & so on?

Comment: @user2181397 Yes, the same.

Comment: Is 200 a static number? You could destructure it with `[panoX, panoY] = 200;`

Comment: The first `if` condition isn't really different from the `else`, so this could be a decent use of ternary – `let panoX = pano.x === null ? 200 : pano.x;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function panoFix(x){
   if (x === 0) return 0;
   if (x === null) return 200;
   return x;
}

// This will be sent in a form
{
  x: panoFix(pano.x),
  y: panoFix(pano.y)
}
```

The first condition seems to be redundant (same as the fallback case), so it could be shortened to

```
function panoFix(x) { return x === null ? 200 : x }
```

Comment: maybe, `return (x === null) ? 200 : x;`

Comment: Yes, that first condition seems redundant. Just tried to keep the logic same as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

in JS:

```
var panoX = 200, panoY = 200;
if(pano !== null){
  panoX = pano.x;
  panoY = pano.y;
}
```